# Не собирается проект в Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Есть такой вебпак-конфиг, который должен собрать код, пропустив его через Babel и Min-css. До подключения Babel и Min-css конфиг работал. Консоль выдает "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '.index.js'", а терминал-"ERROR in multi @babel/polyfill .index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.index.js' in 'C:\Users...\src'
@ multi @babel/polyfill .index.js main[1]". Еще и css-файл не создается(

```js
const path = require('path')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './index.js'],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'bundle.css'
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы как минимум забыли import "@babel/polyfill";

Comment: @Дедотмороз, спасибо, конечно, но там в документации к нему написано, что вроде как достаточно его указать в массиве entries, ну и установить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в некорректно установленном Babel, переустановил его и все заработало)